# How to flatten a face to avoid distortion (make an ngon planar)

Tags: modeling, normals

I created a kind of procedural modeled ground (rocks desert like), with some decimate modifiers to have a really crazy topology.

The result is nice, except for some ngons faces that contains some weird normals, due to the elevation difference of several vertices:

[image]

How to avoid this? My first guess is to "flatten the face, but I can't figure out the way to do this operation.

I must specify that the face is not perpendicular to the Z axis, so a zero-Z-scaling (<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>) won't work here.

Comment: This question doesn't state if you mean to flatten a single face - or many.

Comment: Update, this is now included in Blender 2.75, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32276/55

Comment: For a very complete answer, see a duplicate question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46268/52815

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can scale along the normal.

Set the *Transform orientation* to *Normal* in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

Then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: so useful! I have spent hundreds of hours in Blender without knowing that was possible.

Answer (score 21):

Since version 2.76 there is a flatten faces tool:

> Mesh -> Cleanup -> Make Planar Faces

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the flatten tool. This tool is part of an add-on that comes bundeled with blender. It is called "Loop Tools"

[image]

You can invoke it by going to the loops tools in the specials menu, <kbd>W</kbd> -> Loop Tools -> Flatten.
[image]

You can enable it in the user preferences:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>
2. go to the Addon Tab
3. Search for "Loop Tools"
4. Enable it by ticking the checkmark

[image]

Comment: This one works to flatten any surface even on angles, while the others above this post only seem to work when directly on the ground. Maybe I couldn't figure out the others but this one solved my issue and is great for cleaning a messy mesh while retaining rotations. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

A  simpler approach to the first answer would be, go to Object Properties -> Scale. And change the x y z value to 0 according to your needs.