# Blender 2.8 carving a circle out of the face of a cube using the knife tool

Tags: knife-tool

In Blender 2.8, I am trying to cut a circle out of one face of a cube, but for some reason I can't get it to work.  My procedure thus far:

(a) Add the cube (add -> mesh -> cube)
(b) Add the circle (add -> Curve -> Circle)
(c) Position the circle in front of the face to be carved
(d) Select the circle; while holding shift add the cube as a selection
(e) Switch to edit mode
(f) Select the knife project (mesh -> knife project)

And I get the result below.  My challenges are:

(1) The cut lines are wrong (the only cut lines should be the circle itself; the straight lines running from the circle to the cube's two vertices are unwanted)
(2) I have no idea how to make the cut actually happen at this point if I had the cut lines that I wanted.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh/15688#15688 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/topology-question-regarding-circular-holes

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-hole-into-an-object/30997#30997