# object turns black when rotating in view

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image: turns black when rotating]

Hi I i'm trying to render this logo out but I notice that it is black when it is sideways. No idea why it's doing this, any help or tips would be great. Thanks

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Can you show screenshots of the object while in Edit mode ? Also could it be that there is some unrenderable object in the scene just behind this one and the black area is visible because this object partially gets inside of that one ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2e47b0c99ec3722435b64dec141b8204
https://gyazo.com/0f5fd0c309438bf2b8a4bd4b5416b2c6
https://gyazo.com/24c2ad76095f7cf2c63c6f2e34035613

sorry about the links i can't add more than two photos since i'm new. It doesn't appear to be because of some unrenderable object, I unhide everything and moved them and still showing up black. also when I rotate around the object it's not black. Only when I am viewing it completely sideways.

Comment: Try recalculating normals in Edit mode with all selected (press `Ctrl`+`N`). If this doesn't solve please [upload the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: did not work :/ thanks for helping here is the file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1156" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1156/)

Comment: Tbh I don't see [anything bad](http://i.imgur.com/TOhIyyk.jpg) while it's rendered (images are other ones because yours weren't [packed into blend](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-any-way-to-save-background-images-in-the-blend-file), but I don't think this is the reason). The central face is very big 236-Ngon though, which *could* cause this behaviour because of bad shading of such enormous face; however to fix it you will need to use *Grid Fill* I think.

Comment: you're like the greatest human ever. thanks for helping me with this silly problem. I think I fixed it by using subdivide/smooth. Fingers crossed. Again, couldn't thank you enough

Comment: how do I give you points for helping me

Comment: what does Ngon mean. There's no more black because I subdiv it a bunch but there are some "stretch marks" i see. updated the image about so you can take a look

Comment: disregard the stretch marks comment

Comment: Is there anything black (or no background ) that is getting reflected at that angle maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see black artifacts on rendered model and you know that all [normals are facing correct direction](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker), then most likely it's still bad shading of faces. It will be present because of inappropriate topology of the mesh.

Taking into consideration your example, the reason for black artifacts is Ngon (face with more than 4 vertices, in your case n = 256) in the middle of the mesh. More than that, this face is non-planar (the vertices which form it aren't located on the same imaginary plane):

[image: Ngon in the middle of the mesh]

To fix this first make the face flat (and vertex loop which forms this face being located on flat "surface" too); then either inset the face (more a workaround than a solution) *or* fill it with new faces.

Start with flattening Ngon.
Use scaling along normals for that (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, choose *Normal* and scale, see [How to flatten a face to avoid distortion (make an ngon planar)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/how-to-flatten-a-face-to-avoid-distortion-make-an-ngon-planar) for more info).

[image: flatten Ngon]

**Insetting Ngon**

Once face is flat inset it to avoid presence of Ngon near the curved area of the mesh. Press <kbd>I</kbd> and change *Thickness* value of insetting.

[image: insetting Ngon]

However this isn't the best solution as the vertices will start overlapping when insetted further than half of the original Ngon. This way is easier though as it creates less geometry which is easier to select / handle with.

**Fill with new faces**

Delete the big face (choose *Faces* in *Delete* menu), select boundary loop and use *Grid Fill* via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or *Mesh* > *Faces* menu in 3D View header:

[image: filled faces]

*Note that this way create extra geometry at the cost of "all-quads". Beware that this can affect on render times / performance. Also it may be more difficult to handle with bigger amount of faces / verts. You may want to add created faces to a new vertex group while they are selected.*

Do the same with second Ngon on the other side of mesh.