# Strange lighting on model

Tags: normals, lighting

[image]

So as you can see there is some very weird lighting on the body of my model. My initial thought was that it was the normals, however after recalcualting and checking manually that they were facing the correct direction, still nothing changed.[image]

Thoughts? Also, sorry if it's an obvious answer, i'm new to blender

Comment: You are dealing with non planar geometry. You need more detail in your mesh.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this post useful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55608/1853

Comment: [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/734/2217) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have smooth shading enabled. To switch to flat shading, select the mesh and on the left side menu, go to the tools panel and choose flat shading.