# Image applied as a UV texture is deformed

Tags: mesh, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I am trying to apply an image with a horizon line of a city on a plane.

[image]

The face I'm trying to apply it to is like a trapezoid shape.

[image]

But when I preview the render in rendered view, the horizon line seems skewed (bottom right preview):

[image]

If I change the size of the two vertices on the left in UV image viewer, I get a rendered preview that makes me feel like the plane isn't really plane, and that Blender is adding an invisible edge to deal with this:

[image]

I've found this question here "[How to flatten a face to avoid distortion (make an ngon planar)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/how-to-flatten-a-face-to-avoid-distortion-make-an-ngon-planar)", but none of the solutions on this question helped solve it.

**Blend:**

[image]

<sub>Note: this model is inspired from the works of [Patrick Hughes](http://design-milk.com/reversed-perspective-patrick-hughes/).</sub>

Comment: it's easier to help you if you pack the images as part of the file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for what you are trying to do you need to set the right ortho view and unwrap using project from view (bounds):

[image]

Then set your material to actually use that newly created UV map as coordinates:

[image]

[image]

If you still have some deformation, use a subsurf modifier, but instead of the default Catmul-Clark subdivision use Simple

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you "[pack the image/imbed it into the file](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/image.html#image-settings)"?
the texture isnt in the .blend file.

I think what you need to do is edit the UV island to be a square instead of a trapezoid

Comment: to ask for clarification on the question please use comments.